# calculate kurtosis for each sequence or intervall in array

Tags: python, arrays, kurtosis

I have an array with 1000(rows) values and I want to calculate for every 10 values the kurtosis in the order from the first value zero to 999 of my array. So, in the end, I would have 100 kurtosis values from the list. Then I want to put all the kurtosis values into one list. The variable does not matter, it is just that I am new to Python and do not know much about it. Appreciate all your help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are lots of resources out there for learning python! To point you in the right direction, googling "python kurtosis" showed me that the `scipy` module has a function `scipy.stats.kurtosis` that can calculate the kurtosis of a dataset. Good luck!

Comment: so far I just calculated it for the whole array, meaning for all 1000 rows with the function from scipy.stats.kurtosis. But I want to do that for each 10 variables. I just do not know how to loop this and make a list to to put each kurtosis value in it.

Comment: Could you post your code please? [Loops](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Loops) are really powerful and worth learning how to use. You also might need to understand [how to use array indexing in Numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) (i.e. how to refer to certain sub-arrays within a larger array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import kurtosis

a = np.arange((1000)) #replace a with your array
ks = np.zeros((100))

for i range(100):
   ks[i] = kurtosis(a[i*10:i*10+10])
```

This will loop through the `i`'s, so that when `i = 0`, `a[i*10:i*10+10] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`, when `i = 1`, `a[i*10:i*10+10] = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]`, etc.

`ks` is then a list of 100 kurtosis values.

Comment: Thats what I was looking for! Thank you

Comment: No problem, if you [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) then other people may find it useful too :)